# Promotion: Buy one get one free

Tags: sitecore-commerce

How can we implement a "Buy one get one free" promotion in Sitecore Commerce.

There is no such benefit rule related to this OOTB in Sitecore Commerce.

Comment: what commerce version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sitecore 9.3

Comment: Then you need to create a custom one, you can see the code for custom promotion here - https://github.com/kazimnami/Sitecore.Commerce.Promotions

Answer (score 1):

For Buy 1 get 1, manual add to cart --> Use price card snapshot (tiered pricing)
Example

1. Price for 1 - 10$ each
2. Price for 2 - 5$ each
3. Price for 3-100 - 10$ each

For Buy 1 get 1, if it is auto add to cart --> In SXC 9.3, you can create an action for Free Gift (similar to SXC 10 action).  Once you have the custom action ready, BOGO is as easy as adding a qualification  "if cart item has quantity = 1 of a product" then (action) add free product to cart (custom action)

For Buy N get N, it becomes tricky and you may have to use combinations price cards or build custom actions